# translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints prevents UIButton actions swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

Im programmatically adding a `UIButton` in `Swift`.

```
private let startBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.setTitle("Get Started!", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    btn.layer.zPosition = 3
    return btn
}()
```

Everything's fine except for when I tap the `UIButton`, `ratingButtonTapped()` isn't being called.

```
func ratingButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    print("Button pressed")
}
```

When I change `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `true` `ratingButtonTapped()` gets called.

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

But then the `UIButton` doesn't appear on the screen. I think this has to do with AutoLayout (I'm new to adding elements programmatically). I want to continue using AutoLayout as I want to avoid using visual format and frames. Is there any way this could be done?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where do you add the button as a subview?

Comment: I have two buttons created in code on my "select" screen. Also, I'musing auto layout and therefore turning off the mask flag. It works perfectly on all devices and iOS 9+. Something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: where is your button farm ?

Comment: i added my button in viewDidLoad like so, view.addSubview(startBtn)

Comment: Also, the zPosition is higher than all other elements on the screen

Answer (score 0):

1: Check that your `UIButton` is not covered by another `UIView` above it that prevents the touch to reach your `UIButton`.

2: Check that your `UIButton` is not "outside" of the superView that it has been added to. If you have it inside an `UIView` for example, and the `UIButton` is outside the `UIView` `rect`, then the touches wont reach it.

These problems can occur when you have unintentionally "wrong" layout constraints/frames.